# If we have a group $H$ with $h\in H$, how do I prove that $|h|\ge |h^2|$?

Tags: group-theory

If we have a group $H$ with $h$ being an element in $H$, how would I prove that $|h|$ is greater than or equal to $|h^2|$?

I've looked through my notes to try and help me do this but didn't find anything useful and I'm quite confused to be honest. Help is needed and appreciated.

Sorry about my notation, I'm still navigating myself around the website and haven't quite got to grips with this yet.

Comment: Assuming that $|h|$ means the order of $h$ then $|h| \geq 1$ is the smallest positive integer such that $h^{|h|} = 1$. So it suffices to show that $(h^2)^{|h|} =1$ as well. Do you see why?

Comment: Are you saying that h to the power of the order of h is 1? Is this just something I should know?

Comment: Also do you have any examples where this works? Perhaps it'll make more sense that way too?

Comment: This is the *definition* of the order of $h$. To repeat what @M.Wang said, the order of $h$ is defined to be the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $h^n = 1$.

Comment: Slight technicality (just to be precise): contrary to the definition given by @M.Wang, there is no requirement that $\lvert h \rvert$ be greater than $1$. It's easy to prove that $\lvert h \rvert = 1$ if and only if $h = 1$.

Comment: You can take $H$ as the group of $4$-th roots of unity. Then the element $e^{2 \pi i/4}$ has order $4$ because it is a primitive $4$-th root of unity. The fourth power of $e^{4 \pi i/4}$ is also $1$. So the order of $e^{4 \pi i/4}=-1$ is smaller or equal to $4$. It's actually $2$. 
@diracdeltafunk Thank you, I corrected it already, it was an unfortunate typo :)

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank for the advice on titles, I'll keep that in mind whenever I ask my next question

Answer (score 1):

Let $h\in H$ with $\lvert h\rvert=n$. Consider

$$\begin{align}
(h^2)^n&=h^{2n}\\
&=(h^n)^2\\
&=e^2\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

Thus the order of $h^2$ is *at most* $n$, since, by definition, the order of $h^2$ is the smallest $m$ such that $(h^2)^m=e$.

---

Consider, for example, the group $\Bbb Z_4$ given by the presentation $$\langle a\mid a^4\rangle.$$ In this case $\lvert a\rvert=4$ whereas $(a^2)^2=e,$ so $\lvert a^2\rvert =2\le 4=\lvert a\rvert$.

Another example is the group $\Bbb Z$ given by the presentation $$\langle z\mid\varnothing \rangle.$$ Here both $\lvert z\rvert$ and $\lvert z^2\rvert$ are [$\aleph_0$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number).

Comment: Thank you for the help! Do you know of any examples where this situation holds? I find examples help me to understand things better.

Comment: @Hannah: The order of $h^2$ divides the order of $h$. The order will be equal if $n$ is odd, and will be strictly smaller than $n$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: Is this an expansion on the proof above? Or an example of the situation? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: You're welcome. I've edited my answer, @Hannah.

Comment: Thank you once again! I feel as if the example really helped! I do have one question though ... which I feel bad about. In your second example, I'm not familiar with the notation in the last line which resembles an N. What is that? @Shaun

Comment: @Hannah: It's more information; it's also more than what you asked for, though.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Do you know of any examples where the orders will be equal? I'm trying to think of one in my mind but I'm not getting anywhere, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've updated the answer again, @Hannah. Again, you're welcome.

Comment: @Hannah: As I indicated, the orders are equal if and only if the order of $h$ is odd or infinite. Take the cyclic group of order $3$, and any element there, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Lets prove this using a different view: The order of an element $h\in H$ is equal to the order of the minimal subgroup of $H$ containing $h$, denoted $\langle h\rangle$. That is, $|h|=|\langle h\rangle|$. This is a useful view in general, as for example it allows us to apply Lagrange's Theorem to prove that the order of an element divides the order of the group, so $|h|$ divides $|H|$.

We can use this view to argue as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
h^2&\in\langle h\rangle\\
\Rightarrow \langle h^2\rangle&\leq\langle h\rangle&\text{by minimality of $\langle h^2\rangle$}\\
\Rightarrow |\langle h^2\rangle|&\leq|\langle h\rangle|\\
\Rightarrow |h^2|&\leq|h|
\end{align*}
$$

One can then show that if $|h|$ is odd then $\langle h^2\rangle=\langle h\rangle$, and so $|h^2|=|h|$. Otherwise, $\langle h^2\rangle\lneq\langle h\rangle$, and so $|h^2|\lneq|h|$.